# Caching an eloquent querys and dependency inversion

Tags: php, laravel, caching, dependency-injection, abstract-class

Im learning more about dependency inversion principle in laravel and i'm just wondering !
which is the best approach to cache querys?

exemple

**In the controller**

```
public function edit($id)
    {
         $user = Cache::remember('users', 60, function() { 
            return $this->repo->findorfail($id);
          });
        return view('admin.users.edit', compact('user'));
    }
```

But this way i will have to do this in every function

**in the abstract class**

```
public function findorfail($id)
    {
        return Cache::remember('users', 60, function() { 
                return $this->model->findOrFail($id);
              });
    }
```

I think (be easy on me) this way this will happen for classes that extends it so i wont to type it lots of time

is there a better approach? is this right?

Comment: What class exactly do you mean by **abstract class**?

Comment: its a class where i 'should keep the application logic in' / other classes extends it and implements an interface that eventually will be injected in the desired controller, im still learning this things so i hope you can understand what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the size of your application, doing this all in the controller may be fine. As it grows, you may want to pull the caching out to its own spot, like a base model or repository.

A couple of things to think about when using a Cache.

- Each cache object needs to have a key. You can use that key later to check if there is a cache and invalidate where necessary
- You're responsible for invalidating the cache when data changes. For example, in your example, if something about this User changes, you'll likely want to invalidate and then re-cache. As your application grows this is more difficult than it sounds. Just be mindful of this.

An example might be:

```
// /app/BaseModel.php
<?php

namespace App;

use Cache;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BaseModel extends Model 
{
    public function find($id)
    {
        $key = get_class($this->model) . '_find_' . $id;

        return Cache::remember($key, 60, function() { // the first argument is the key. you'll need to know this to invalidate the cache
            return $this->model->findOrFail($id);
        });
    }

    public function purgeOne($id, $method)
    {
        $key = get_class($this->model) . '_' . $method . '_' . $id ;

        return Cache::forget($key);
    }

    ... maybe you have other cache-related methods
}

// /app/User.php
<?php

namespace App;

use BaseModel;

class User extends BaseModel 
{
   ... stuff specific to your user
}
```

Another idea rather than putting the Cache functionality in a `BaseModel` is to use a `Trait`. The principle is basically the same, but instead you may have a trait named something like `HandlesCache` or `Cacheable`. Use that in any models that are "Cacheable" and you're good to go.

```
// /app/Traits/Cacheable.php
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Cache;

trait Cacheable
{
    public function find($id)
    {
        $key = get_class($this->model) . '_find_' . $id;

        return Cache::remember($key, 60, function() { // the first argument is the key. you'll need to know this to invalidate the cache
            return $this->model->findOrFail($id);
        });
    }

    public function purgeOne($id, $method)
    {
        $key = get_class($this->model) . '_' . $method . '_' . $id ;

        return Cache::forget($key);
    }

    ... maybe you have other cache-related methods
}

// /app/User.php
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Traits\Cacheable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model 
{
    use Cacheable;
    ... stuff specific to your user
}
```

Comment: Edited the answer to make key unique for given user, based on their id.

Comment: My edit did not satisfy you, you prefered to edit yourself... ok.

Comment: "responsible for invalidating the cache when data changes." can this be done by firing an event that if data changes  i mean  is it right? (i have no code but  i will soon so im thinking about the best way to do it) anyway the trait approach is great, thank you

Comment: @Arcesilas I was editing while you were, saw your comment and added the ID. Thanks for the callout. :)

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja Sure. An event or maybe even better a model observer: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-observers? (Not sure why these got removed from more recent documentation, but they're still part of Eloquent in 5+)

Comment: You're welcome, @AchrafKhouadja. Also remember you can flush the entire cache with Artisan: `php artisan cache:clear`. This will come in handy during development or even on deploys.